# Why setInterval (->...) ,0 won't run as I expected?

Tags: coffeescript

From *CoffeeScript Accelerated JavaScript Development*, chapter 6.6, question:

```
count = 10
h = setInterval (-> count--),100
do (->) until count is 0
clearInterval h
console.log 'Suprise!'
```

count won't be 0,I try to change 100 to 0,result is the same.
which stack is the setInterval in? when will the callback function (-> count--) run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is strictly single-threaded.
All asynchronous callbacks will only run after your code finishes running.

Your infinite loop never finishes running, so the `setInterval` callback never runs.